# Replicate Gimp Unsharp Mask with Java - OpenCv

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, implementation, gimp

I'm trying to replicate unsharp mask in Gimp with using Java and OpenCv. I use a grayscale image as input and apply unsharp mask, but results are not even close.

I try to implement this C++ code:

```
Mat blurred; double sigma = 1, threshold = 5, amount = 1;
GaussianBlur(img, blurred, Size(), sigma, sigma);
Mat lowContrastMask = abs(img - blurred) < threshold;
Mat sharpened = img*(1+amount) + blurred*(-amount);
img.copyTo(sharpened, lowContrastMask);
```

And this is my Java implementation:

```
double sigma = 1, threshold = 5, amount = 1;
Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread(input.getName());
Mat destination = new Mat();
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(source, destination, new Size(), sigma, sigma);
Mat lowContrastMask = new Mat();
Core.absdiff(source, destination, lowContrastMask);
Imgproc.threshold(lowContrastMask, lowContrastMask, 0, threshold, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
Mat sharpened = new Mat();
Core.multiply(source, new Scalar(0), sharpened, amount+1);
Mat sharpened2 = new Mat();
Core.multiply(destination, new Scalar(0), sharpened2, -amount);
Core.add(sharpened2, sharpened, sharpened);
source.copyTo(sharpened, lowContrastMask);
```

Alternative Unsharp Masking method:

```
Mat source = Imgcodecs.imread(input.getName());
Mat destination = new Mat();
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(source, destination, new Size(0,0), 60);
Core.addWeighted(source, 1.5, destination, -1, 0, destination);
```

So, both methods are working but results are and not good as gimp result. I'm open to any suggestion. I know it look like a bad implementation. I'm a newbie, I appreciate any help.